# Delete a tag with github v3 API

Tags: github-api

I can create an annotated tag using the GitHub v3 API by following [their directions](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/). I create the tag object, then the ref object. Everything good there.

I can delete the *reference* like this:

```
curl -X DELETE -i -u 'myuser:mypassword' https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/git/refs/tags/ben-test-310
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be sufficient. How do I fully delete the tag using the API?

Comment: The only way I can fully delete the tag is with "git tag -d :tag" and then "git push origin :refs/tags/:tag".

Comment: Six years passed, they still did not provide this API.

Answer (score 5):

The API supports this now. It's called "deleting a ref" (`delete_ref`):

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#delete-a-reference

Here it is in the Ruby SDK also, just for example:
https://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Refs.html

Answer (score 3):

Had to figure out that I needed to prepend `/tags` before the tag I wanted to delete but it's not mentioned in https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#delete-a-reference.

Here's the full command for reference:

```
curl \
  -X DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer {GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repo}/git/refs/tags/{tag}"
```