# Completely delete release with GitHub API

Tags: github, release

I'm trying to use the GitHub web API to delete and existing release if present like:

```
curl -u user:pw --request DELETE "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/releases/RELEASE_ID"
```

this deletes the release message, but leaves a tag with the assets which seems to require manual removal. Is there some way to completely delete a release with the GitHub API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the key if to both delete the release id and tag, that is

```
curl -u user:pw --request DELETE "$URL/releases/$RELEASE_ID_TO_DELETE"
curl -u user:pw --request DELETE "$URL/git/refs/tags/$TAG_TO_DELETE"
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to couple that with:

- First: [listing the assets](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-assets-for-a-release)
- [deleting each asset](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#delete-a-release-asset)

And also: [delete the ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49905989/6309) represented by the tag associated to this release.

Answer (score 0):

With [GitHub CLI gh 2.18.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases), you can do a

```
gh release delete <tag> [--cleanup-tag]
```

That will clean up the associated remote tag on GitHub.

And [GitHub CLI v2.35.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.35.0), Sept. 2023, will also delete the *local* tag when using [`gh release delete --cleanup-tag <tag>`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_delete)